# RESTful service URL and security

Tags: rest, service

I proposed including filtering information and the usual URL approach to access resources through a RESTful service.

A client is concerned that the URL will contain information which they do not want logged by a web server or other infrastructure applications.

What alternatives could there be?

Comment: What were you proposing? "The usual URL approach" is not meaningful.

Comment: You can secure it by using https RESTfull service and using by POST method.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your web server to not log those information. This is how it would look like in case of Nginx:

At the `http` level:

```
log_format scrubbed '"$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
    '"$scrubbed_request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

At the `server` level:

```
access_log /var/log/access.log scrubbed;
```

At the `location` level:

```
set $scrubbed_request $request;

if ($scrubbed_request ~ (.*)sensitive=[^&]*(.*)) {
   set $scrubbed_request $1sensitive=****$2;
}
```

Code is taken from [here](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/congress/tree/master/config/nginx#suppressing-user-latitudelongitude-in-our-logs), visit that link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about being religiously Restful, you could submit everything using POST or PUT over SSL.  Post parameters are not logged (like the GET url is) in webserver logs.

If it's only Authentication details that you don't want recorded (like client_id & client_secret) you can use the authorization header.

Comment: we given the same answer same time

Comment: @prashantthakre looks like my answer beat your comment by a few seconds.  Maybe we're psychic siblings.

Comment: In RESTful services all verbs including post and put usually have the same paths and parameters in the URL to identify the resource.  So how exactly would I include this information in the request?  In a header?  And a single URL would be used for all requests?

Comment: @user3915768 No reason you can't specify them in the POST body or use HTTP basic auth to encode them in the header--this doesn't get recorded in logs either.

Comment: @user3915768  if it's JUST authentication credential you can use GET and headers.  If if it's other parameters as well, you'll need to stick them in the POST body.  I wouldn't create custome headers.